# What to do when you have massive amount of data but you don't have enough computation power for training a machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-preprocessing

For example, I have a massive amount of data, but I have limited computational resources and time to train on the full data. Other cases may include, I have huge amounts of 360-degree images, where I need to train on full-size images (without cropping down), but I have limited computation power (GPU, RAM, etc.), what can I do in those cases?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this question without knowing what your goal is, but if your data is extensive, high quality, especially if it is labelled, and no similar dataset is publicly available, then publishing it freely with some kind of challenge could be very helpful if that's an option. Many organisations have the opposite problem: available computing resources but lack of data. If your data are new and interesting, I could imagine researchers wanting to use it. If people get good results, they may publish them, good for AI generally, and presumably also useful to you. If you do this of course you would need to publicise it a bit so people become aware of it.